# Reading circular read mapping (BAM) into R with readGAlignments()

Tags: r, bioconductor

I am trying to create a circular genome map in R using the ggbio package. I am new to ggbio and related packages like GenomicAlignments and GenomicRanges.

I exported my read mapping as a BAM file (with associated index file) and tried to use readGAlignmentsFromBam() to read in the file.

```
    myreads <- readGAlignmentsFromBam("final.assembly", index = "final.assembly", use.names = TRUE)
```

But I always get

Warning message:
In GenomicRanges:::valid.GenomicRanges.seqinfo(x) :
GAlignments object contains 12006 out-of-bound ranges located on sequence
Consensus. Note that only ranges located on a non-circular sequence whose
length is not NA can be considered out-of-bound (use seqlengths() and
isCircular() to get the lengths and circularity flags of the underlying
sequences).

Which makes sense - it's a circular chromosome, so some reads will be outside of the "linear" reference sequence. The question is, how do I fix it? I've attempted adding isCircular = c(TRUE) as an argument, but that did not help. It would seem there is a flag somewhere (in the BAM file? in the R code?) that should be set which isn't, but I can't figure out where.

Apologies for not having a reproducible example, but this is a huge BAM file and I am not familiar enough with the file type to mock up the data.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that exact error, but a few ideas. How many reads are in your BAM file, 12000 out of bounds may be a tiny fraction of your total amount and could simply be reads that didn't map properly. What is the output of `isCiruclar(myreads)` and `seqlengths(myreads)`. I'm curious if the BAM file is flagged as circular. Also from the command line what does `samtools view -H final.assembly` show. I'd like to see what is in the bam header.

Comment: @jraab isCircular(myreads) yields: Consensus NA. seqlengths(myreads): Consensus 14712. And from samtools:                                                    HD VN:1.0 SO:coordinate
SQ SN:Consensus LN:14712
RG ID:Paired Group 1 assembled against Consensus PI:100 SM:Contig
RG ID:Unpaired reads assembled against Consensus SM:Contig